# Perl : DBD::ODBC::st execute failed

Tags: perl

I am getting following errors :

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at test.pl line 29, <$fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $col in split at test.pl line 40, <$fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $k in hash element at test.pl line 41, <$fh> line 2.
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '
,'. (SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQL-42000) at da
ve.pl line 63, <$fh> line 2.
Can't execute statement: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (
SQL-42000)
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (SQL-42000) at te
st.pl line 63, <$fh> line 2.
```

and I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

My [code is here](http://pastebin.com/UF0A3Cn7) with input data.

Or any other better solution for this task (reading data from input file, manipulate data and insert value in corresponding column into database table.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL INSERT INTO Syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

And you are getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'` because you forgot to close the parenthesis `)` in `$sql` after column names,

try this:

```
my $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (' .
            join(', ', keys %data) .
            ') VALUES (' .
            join(', ', map { qq['$_'] } values %data) .
            ')';
```

or, even better, use [`RaiseError`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#RaiseError) for convenience and safety, [identifier quoting](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#quote_identifier) for correctness and safety, [query parameterization](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) for efficiency and safety, and perhaps [`do()`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#do) it rather than `prepare`/`execute`:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(..., { RaiseError => 1 });
my $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (' .
            join(', ', map { $dbh->quote_identifier($_) } keys %data) .
            ') VALUES (' .
            join(', ', map { '?' } keys %data .
            ')';

my $num_inserted = $dbh->do($sql, undef, values %data); # We don't really need a distinct $sth
```

DBD::ODBC also supports [other placeholder syntax](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.50/ODBC.pm#Mixed_placeholder_types), too.

Comment: But my code is inserting one extra lines into database with 0 value for all columns. Can you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: +1 I added a bit about query parameterization, etc., to your answer.  Rollback or edit if you think that was inappropriate.

Comment: @pilcrow: Thanks for improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

On line 27, add

```
warn "[$_]";
```

And see why `parse_line` returns `undef`.

Also, as some strings seem to be quoted, it might be better to switch to `quotewords` instead of `parse_line`.

Comment: Don't know why is value undef, It should take `0` for `flapPreventionWaitCycles` but its not taking.

Comment: @user4752537: What does the `warn` return?

Comment: The empty `[]` or `[ ]` is more important for the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @user10: I'm getting the warnings for empty input lines. For non-empty lines, there are no warnings.

Comment: But there is no empty lines in input file.

Comment: @user10: There are lines containing only one space in the pastebin. When I remove them, I get no warnings.

Comment: There is no line space in original text file. There are total 17 lines with two new lines chraracter at last.

Comment: @user10: I can't reproduce your problem, then.

Comment: I didn't see any blank line in my text file. but when I copy and paste it in `Notepad++` it shows a blank line after each non-empty line.

Comment: Print the sql, check what's wrong with it. Have you switched to `quotewords`?

Comment: Print the sql, check what's wrong with it. Have you switched to `quotewords`?

Comment: Now it inserting the data into table but problem is there are only 16 data but its inserting 17 lines and the value of 17th line (last line) is 0 for all columns. how can get rid of from this extra line?

Comment: @user10: There's probably another empty line at the very end of the input.

Comment: Then how to remove those empty lines?

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `'[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]'`, then I figured it was the ODBC driver configured. In my case, the ODBC driver selected was `'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'`, but other similar servers had it set up as `'SQL Server Driver'`. Make sure the correct driver is selected and configured.

[image: ODBC Driver]